# Setting color of elements with javascript based on text

Tags: javascript, css, events, onload

I have a table with some values that I want to set the color based on the value they have. What I did was this:

```js
window.onload = setColor();

function setColor() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].innerText === "Passed") {
      elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (elems[i].innerText === "Failed") {
      elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">SET</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">TEST STATUS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Set</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Set</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But as you can see, I'm looping overall `td elements` to do that and I think that isn't good, is it?

So I have some questions in mind:

- Is there a workaround to set up some kind of `onload events` for `elements` that do not support it so I could do something like `magicevent=setColor(this)`? I expect the table to be stable.
- Is what I asked in last question a good practice? If not, what would you recommend?
- How could I have achieved what I did in `CSS`? I don't understand the syntax of `CSS` within `js`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest to add a key-up event handler on each td and monitor the inner text of the td in the event handler and if it's Passed or Failed add a class to it that contains the required styles.

Comment: what you might do instead is to also set a class on td according to the text inserted , so you do not have to deal with style via js nor make a loop everywhere. do that check a few steps earlier ;)

Comment: How many cells are you expecting? A few hundred? Don't worry about it. Tens of thousands? Maybe do some chunking, i.e. style a hundred at a time so the first few rows are styled right away instead. If you can do it on the backend I'd do that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try answer to your questions:

- Your solution is stable and it works in all browsers. Another way to achieve it could be to render the `td` tags with a specific class and give to the class a css rule without using javascript.

Something like:

```
    <style>
     .failed{
       background-color: red; 
     }
     .passed{
      background-color: green;
     }
    </style>

    <table>
    <tr><td class="failed">failed </td></tr> 
    <tr><td class="passed">passed </td></tr>
    </table>
```

- Your solution is stable. Keep in mind that it could be slow if your table has thousands of rows.
- When you use  `elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";` you are setting the `background-color` of the element inside `elems` in position `i`. Inside `elems[i]` there is a specific `td`.
  Another approach is adding a class to a `td` based on value of test (passed or failed). 
  However, I suggest the following solution:

  `<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:50%;">SET</th>
      <th style="width:50%;">TEST STATUS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set</td>
      <td>Passed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set</td>
      <td>Passed</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <style>
  .failed{
    background-color: red; 
  }
  .passed{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  window.onload = setColor();
  function setColor(){
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          if (elems[i].innerText === "Passed") {
            elems[i].classList.add("passed");
    }else if (elems[i].innerText === "Failed"){
       elems[i].classList.add("failed");
    }
   }
  }
  </script>`

Comment: Thank you, Wolfetto, 
In this case I don't expect a huge amount of rows, but since I'm learning and I was going to ask anyway why not ask for a performant way of solving the issue :D
I also noticed that by using `getElements` or by using `QuerySelectorAll` I'll have to iterate over all elements but in the second way I'll have a "smaller" second iteration which I think is better. But I'm wondering are there other ways to gather all elements besides these?
Having the classes added by backend as suggested in one comment above is not possible in my case at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your script could be changed to something like this:

```js
function setColor(){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td:last-child");
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      if (elems[i].innerText === "Passed") {
          elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
      else if (elems[i].innerText === "Failed")
      {
          elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setColor);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th style="width:50%;">SET</th>
    <th style="width:50%;">TEST STATUS</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Set</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Set</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But it would be better to use CSS classes for coloring text:

```js
  if (elems[i].innerText === "Passed") {
      elems[i].classList.add("passed");
  }
  else if (elems[i].innerText === "Failed")
  {
      elems[i].classList.add("failed");
  }
```

In style.css:

```
.passed {
  background-color: green;
}
.failed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I guess that `querySelectorAll` iterates overall elements and returns the ones that match, so your idea to search them is better compared with mine since I'm iterating overall elements once to see if they are `td` and once more to see if they have the `innerText` value.